# How to have two elements with scrollbars next to each other?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm currently programming a view, that contains two list elements that can move information between each other. Here's a picture of how it currently looks:

[image: Demo]

I supposedly have in the page a lot of space to the right of the table "CodigoAGrupador" for the table "Catalogos" to fit in, and it used to do so, but when I added the scrollbars, suddenly, they can only be together vertically, never horizontally.

Here's the CSS code:

```
#products {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #cart {
        width: 400px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        float: right;
        max-height: 600px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        margin: 2px,2px,2px,2px;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    #ListaCodigos{
        max-height:600px;
        width:500px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        margin: 2px,2px,2px,2px;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

And here's the code that I use for the html view (it contains logic that I use to dynamically create the lists, that part shouldn't be the issue)

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="ListaCodigos">
        <h2 class="ui-widget-header">CodigoAgrupador</h2>
        <div id="products">
            <div id="catalog">
                @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
                {
                    if (unchecked(double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) == (int)double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador)))
                    {
                        <h3><a href="#">@c.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c.NombreCuenta</a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <div class="subcatalog">
                                @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c2 in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
                                {
                                    if (double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) > double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) && double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) < (double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) + 1))
                                    {
                                        <h4><a href="#">@c2.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c2.NombreCuenta</a></h4>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="SpecificCatalog">
                                                <ol>
                                                    <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                                </ol>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="GeneralCatalog">
                                <ol>
                                    <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart">
        <h2 class="ui-widget-header">Catalogos</h2>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            @foreach (LedgerChartOfAccounts c in Model.Catalogos)
            {
                if (c.CodigoAgrupador == null)
                {
                    <ul>
                        <li class="draggable">@c.GLAccountNumber  - @c.GLAccountName  </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <footer>Inserte los catalogos en el grupo que pertenescan, jale.</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

It probably is a very simple issue, but I couldn't find any specific answer to my problem and I already have struggled for quite a while. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `float:left` the `menu` and `ListaCodigos` to get it to pull up.  Make sure that `content` is wide enough to hold them both on one line however.

However, then after `menu` `div` you will want to add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Comment: I can't believe that I forgot to add float:left to ListaCodigos when I already had added float to everything else.

I just added that, and it is fixed. Thank you.